# How to spawn NPCs that has creature_template?

Tags: azerothcore

I have added `mod-npc-all-mounts`. This has SQL script that I execute to create `creature_template` with ID 601014.

How do I spawn this NPC to various locations in the game ?

I have tried `.npc add 601014` and `.npc add temp 601014` on a GM account but I just see the help text for, npc commands which suggests `.npc add` might not be a valid command

Answer (score 1):

Check https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/gm-commands
It shows the available commands and the required GM levels.

There is also `account set gmlevel` to grant an account GM rights. This goes to the worldserver console. It needs to login *after* the rights were changed.